# Objective-C: How can the object p know the changes of Person class after Person class is changed?

Tags: objective-c

How can the object p know the content of Person class is changed? like this:

Before Person class changed:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Person:NSObject

@end

int main(){
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
    return 0;
 }
```

After Person class changed:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Person:NSObject
@property int age;/* add a new member */
- (void)test;     /* add a new method */
@end
@implememtation Person
- (void)test
{
   NSLog(@"Hello");
}
@end

int main(){
     Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
     return 0;
}
```

How can the object p know that Person are added with a new member and a new method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MonitoringMemoryUsage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH33-SW1) and the Allocations template and enter "Person" in the search box.   If the Person object is presently in memory it will be in the list.

Comment: thank for your answer for my first question.